# Convert from Decimal to Binary by using long long int, unsigned int and ostream&

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert Decimal number to Binary number by using long long int, unsigned int and ostream&. Everything went fine until the part where the Binary result, apparently now I have an LNK1120 and LNK2019 error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

vector<unsigned int> ganzeZahl(unsigned long long int binary);
ostream& dualZahl(ostream& out, const vector<unsigned int>& ganzeZahl);


//This part is to print out the Binary number at the end.
ostream& dualZahl(ostream& out, vector<unsigned int>& ganzeZahl)
{
    if (out)
    {
        unsigned int dualZahl{};
        while (out << dualZahl)
        {
            ganzeZahl.push_back(dualZahl);
        }
        out.clear();
    }
    return out;
}

//This part is where the decimal number will be changed to binary number.
vector<unsigned int> ganzeZahl(unsigned long long int binary)
{
    vector<unsigned int> ergebnis;
    while (binary > 0)
    {
        ergebnis.push_back(binary % 2);
        binary /= 2; 
    }
    return ergebnis;
}


int main()
{
    cout << " \n\t Umwandlung von positiven Integern in dualen Zahlen. "
        << "\n\t ---------------------------------------------------\n"
        << endl;

    cout << "\n\t Geben Sie eine Zahl : ";
    unsigned long long int zahl1;
    cin >> zahl1;

    vector<unsigned int> dZahl1 = ganzeZahl(zahl1);
    cout << "\tDual : ";
    dualZahl(cout, dZahl1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you print in `dualZahl`, the first thing you do to the vector is calling `clear()`, why?

Comment: it will be better to translate funktions names + coments to english

Comment: can you explain what `dualZahl` is supposed to do? It is really difficult to understand

Comment: It is more efficient to [debug small programs yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), than to use Stack Overflow as your debugger.

Comment: this looks like a good case for [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). If your duck does not understand the code unlikely others will ;)

Comment: `std::bitset` maybe?

Comment: As almost invariably in these questions, there is no decimal to binary conversion here, other than at `cin >> zahl1;`. After that, the value is binary.